# Getting Error from java while consuming Dynamics Ax Web services

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, soap, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to Dynamics Ax Web services.

I am consuming DocSalesOrder service from java by creating following request :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
xmlns:dat="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2010/01/datacontracts"
xmlns:ent="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKeyList"
xmlns:ent1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey"
xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <dat:CallContext>
        <dat:Company>cee</dat:Company>
        <dat:Language>en-us</dat:Language>
        <dat:LogonAsUser>domain\userName</dat:LogonAsUser>
        <dat:MessageId>a33ee45b-5550-4118-9be3-0d8038c7fb85</dat:MessageId>
        <dat:PropertyBag>
            <arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
                <arr:Key>SalesId</arr:Key>
                <arr:Value>00000002_050</arr:Value>
            </arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        </dat:PropertyBag>
    </dat:CallContext>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ser:SalesOrderServiceReadRequest>
        <ent:EntityKeyList>
            <ent1:EntityKey>
                <ent1:KeyData>
                    <ent1:KeyField>
                        <ent1:Field>SalesId</ent1:Field>
                        <ent1:Value>00000002_050</ent1:Value>
                    </ent1:KeyField>
                </ent1:KeyData>
            </ent1:EntityKey>
        </ent:EntityKeyList>
    </ser:SalesOrderServiceReadRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This request is working fine from SoapUI. But from java i am getting error as

**"javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No matching MessageFilter was found for the given message."**

I have searched on google. But some people are saying the Messagefilter is missing in Soap Header.

But I don't see any tag for filtering in Soap Header. This request is working fine from SOAP UI.

Please help me out. I am struggling with this since last 3 days.

Comment: turn on wcf logging on the server, then compare the working and failing messages. one option is that the messages should have ws-addressing headers. another is that there should be an http header SOAPAction. check both

Comment: I added the action tag in the soap header like

Comment: you need to provide a sample working request and a sample failing one. also you need to provide not only the soap but also http headers for each sample, especially content-type and soapaction.